# Green turtle/Snail Mode (Slow Performance indicator) on Virtualbox VM

Tags: windows, virtualbox, windows-11

So the green turtleSnail mode for "emulation mode" remains stubbornly active.
On a Windows 11 host running a Windows 11 VM.
[image: Green turtle slow performance, unusable...]

VirtualBox 7.0.6
W11 settings: `Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName *hyper*`
shows all settings as disabled.

The Dell PC has Virtualization active in Bios.
[image: BIOS screen shot]

VirtualBox VM config
[image: Nested VT-x is active]
[image: Hardware Virtualization is set to default]

[image: Core Isolation memory protection is off]
[image: Group Policy Virtualization is Off]

Hyper-V is off
Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) is off.
Windows Sandbox is off
[image]

Just in case I also ran
`bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype Off`

I also ran

```
./VBoxManage modifyvm "Virtual Machine Name" --nested-hw-virt on
```

which also wonder if the falsely gives you the impression
Enabled Nested VT-x is working as expeted.

My user has Admin rights on the PC.

What have I done wrong or forgotten?
Any ideas why the the beloved blue turtle doesnt want to play?

**EDIT:**

FINALLY a solution.
i downloaded device from MIcrosoft.
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=53337

Extracted the scripts and ran

```
DG_readiness_tool.ps1 -Disable
```

And rebooted.

on Restart Speccy and System Info show an available Virtualization environment.    Device Guard was my issue.

Comment: Your question is not clear.  What "blue turtle" are you referring to exactly?

Comment: I added a screen shot to explain. The Turtle should be blue if virtualization setup works.
When it doesnt, it has to emulate.   Which is unusably slow.

Comment: What other software do you have installed that might be using hardware virtualization other than VirtualBox?

Comment: good question.... Ill check what might be active.  Nothing that Im aware of, but you make a good point.

Comment: shame people dont mention why they vote to close the questions. What can i do to improve the question ?

Comment: What I would do here is (a) make sure VMs are backed up; (b) uninstall VBOX; (c) restart the computer; (d) ensure Hyper-V is truly OFF (all Hyper-V stuff);  (e) check Core Isolation - it does not always work so if OFF you can dismiss it. Install VBOX and check .  Your question is decent and I did not downvote it.

Comment: The VM is new and easy to redo, so no backup required. I rebooted, core isolation memory integrity is still off.   In powershell , Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName *hyper*      shows everything is still disabled.
Im going to revisit the BIOS settings now.

Comment: @philsoady - Core Isolation isn't required for VirtualBox to use VT-x.  Task Manager would indicate if Virtualization was accessible to VirtualBox.  Your Settings page screenshot does not tell a great deal; nested virtualization isn't what determines if VirtualBox itself has access to VT-x. I also assume you are getting a VirtualBox error dialog indicating VT-x isn't accessible (i.e. VERR_NEM_VM_CREATE_FAILED)

Comment: @ramhound, no there was no error dialog . I wasnt aware that Task Manager would indicate if Virtualization was accessible to VirtualBox.   Ill check that now. 
I just deleted the VM and was planning to reinstall it.
Ill include the logs on after reinstalling the VM

Comment: Deleting the VM won't solve the underline problem of VT-x being inaccessible to VirtualBox

Comment: Regarding your earlier comment, "shame people don't mention why they vote to close the questions.", the close reasons are the reason for the vote. Do I agree that a community bot comment should display which close reason(s) is being voted on? Don't expect users to explain their close reason, I almost never do because of the personal attacks that have been thrown at me in the past.

Comment: Ok, I understand that point Ramhound, on the close, and personal attacks.  But as a 10ker on Stackoverflow who has closed a question or 2, Im genuinely interested in the why.  Nothing personal.  I also know it wasnt you. You have also answered one of my past questions.  :)

Comment: A script i found here https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=53337  run with -Disable was the solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is annoying as hell. I experienced the same problem, at first thinking the Intel Alder Lake performance/efficient core architecture was at fault (someone else suspected that too at https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=108745), but then noticed the green turtle symbol and found https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=99390

I tried everything that the second VirtualBox thread mentioned:

- `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off` (although I couldn't do the full
  power cycle since I can't remove the laptop battery)
- `DISM /Online /Disable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V`
- I put Enabled to 0 under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, SYSTEM, CurrentControlSet, Control, DeviceGuard, Scenarios, SystemGuard.
- I put EnableVirtualizationBaseSecurity and EnableVirtualizationBasedSecurity just in case there was a typo to 0 under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, SYSTEM, CurrentControlSet, Control, DeviceGuard.
- I set Memory Integrity to Off
- I checked BIOS settings, disabling Secure Boot and some features that seemed to offer additional security by using virtualization

...but I couldn't get the green turtle away, even after reboots. msinfo32.exe showed that virtualization-based security was still in use.

I think msinfo32.exe here is key tool: if it reports that virtualization-based security is in use, VirtualBox has no chance of working. Apparently VMWare works better, not sure why, either it's possible it integrates better with Windows virtualization support, or it's possible VMWare has more responsive emulation mode when emulated virtualization has to be used.

Naturally, I did check that virtualization was enabled in BIOS settings.

Then I found the solution:

1. Go to Control Panel, select Programs and Features, select Turn Windows features on or off
2. Remove Hyper-V
3. Remove Windows Hypervisor Platform
4. Remove Virtual Machine Platform
5. Save settings and reboot

In my case, Windows Hypervisor Platform was still checked and this was causing Windows to boot inside hypervisor, so the virtualization features were already in use and VirtualBox couldn't use the CPU's virtualization features.