Why does Windows 11 on VirtualBox v7.1.4 show the turtle icon for slowness?
We noticed that the turtle icon is always on after upgrading the physical host from Windows 10 to Windows 11.
We checked the following configurations:

Task Manager shows Virtualization is Enabled.
Memory integrity is disabled.
We have run bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off.
In "Turn Windows Features On or Off", we have unchecked the following items to disable them: Containers, Hyper-V, Virtual Machine Platform, Windows Sandbox, Windows hypervisor Platform.

Nevertheless, after rebooting the physical host, the guest VMs still have the turtle icon.

Have you reviewed this question and its answer: https://superuser.com/questions/1778061/green-turtle-snail-mode-slow-performance-indicator-on-virtualbox-vm

What security software do you have installed? Do you have Docker installed? Any software that requires hardware virtualization could impact VirtualBox's ability to use it. VirtualBox generates a log which very likely has the necessary information to identify what is preventing it's ability to use hardware virtualization. What guest OS are you trying to run within the VM? How does this question differ from your original question here? The log file is NEM.txt

Many of these answers here apply to your situation.  Instead of the version they specified in the answer, refer to the current version of VirtualBox. The underline cause of this behavior has not changed in the months and years since that question was asked.
